# bindValue parse error, submitting form

Tags: php

Can't seem to get `bindValue()` working on line 158 till 161 (talking about the ones inside of function `'messageUpdate'`), get the error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Help would be appreciated, code is down below. I am trying to let users edit their message if it matches their username, then by using the form it gets submitted back to the same file.

```
<?php
  class editMessage {
    // PROPERTIES,
    // Location of the message page.
    public $MESSAGES_PAGE = 'messages.php';
    // Location of the login page.
    public $LOGIN_PAGE = '../index.php';
    // Lcaotion of the logout script.
    public $LOGOUT_FILE = '../login/logout.php';
    // Stores the id that most likely belongs to a corresponding message.
    private $id;
    // Stores the matching username found from the id using an sql query.
    private $MatchingUsername;
    // Stores fetched message.
    private $fetchedMessage;
    // Store the number of rows resulting from sql query.
    private $NumberofRows;
    // Stores the updated message.
    private $updatedMessage;
    // $MatchingRowNOTFound is used to see if id can be found in database. If it is equal to one, then the id does exist.
    public $MatchingRowNotFound = 0;
    // $MultipleRowsFound, means that there are multiple messages with the same id (more than one). This means that there is an error.
    public $MultipleRowsFound = 1;
    // Maximum String length that can be inputted.
    public $String_MAX_LENGTH = 191;

    // CONSTRUCTOR,
    function __CONSTRUCT($id, $updatedMessage) {
      $this->id = (int) $id;
      $this->updatedMessage = $updatedMessage;
    }

    // METHODS (FUNCTIONS),
    private function ErrorMessage_Redirect() {
      // Delay of two seconds before redirect.
      $delay_seconds = 2;
      // Display the following echoes if requirements where not met. Then after $delay_seconds redirect to login page.
      header('refresh: '.$delay_seconds . ';url= '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE);
      echo "<center>";
        echo "<span style=\"color: red;\">";
          echo "<strong>",'Something went wrong could not retrieve/update message!',"</strong>";
        echo "</span>";
      echo "</center>";
      // Stop the script.
      exit;
    }

    // Function for submitting edited form data.
    public function formSubmit() {
      // For connecting to the database.
      require '../../databases/personalWebserver_PDOmysqlconnect.php';
      // Function(s) relating to login.
      require '../login/login-logout-access_functions.php';

      // Check if user is logged in, running one of the login related function(s).
      LoggedInCheck($this->LOGIN_PAGE);
      LastActivityLogOutCheck($this->LOGOUT_FILE);

      // Fetch the matching username that matches the inputted id, also check that there isn't more than one matching row later on.
      $sql_messageUsername = $conn->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `messageInfo` WHERE `id` = :message_id");
      $sql_messageUsername->bindValue(':message_id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $sql_messageUsername->execute();

      // Save the username inside of a variable.
      $this->MatchingUsername = $sql_messageUsername->fetchColumn();
      // Save the rowCount inside of a variable.
      $this->NumberofRows = $sql_messageUsername->rowCount();

      // Check to see if $id is not empty.
      if ('' === trim($this->id)) {
        // Close database connection.
        $conn = null;
        // Redirect to messages page, because the id is somehow empty.
        header('Location: '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE . '?Idempty');
        // Stop the script.
        exit;
      // Check to see if there is precisely one matching (user)name, belonging to the id number.
      } else if ($this->NumberofRows == $this->MatchingRowNotFound || $this->NumberofRows > $this->MultipleRowsFound) {
        // Close database connection.
        $conn = null;
        // See the function above.
        $this->ErrorMessage_Redirect();
      } else {
        // Check to see whether the user inputted id, matches the current username session.
        if ($this->MatchingUsername === $_SESSION['username']) {
          // Fetch the message from database for editing purposes.
          $sql_fetchMessage = $conn->prepare("SELECT `message` FROM `messageInfo` WHERE `id` = :message_id AND `name` = :username");
          $sql_fetchMessage->bindValue(':message_id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $sql_fetchMessage->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $sql_fetchMessage->execute();
          // Stores the message inside of property.
          $this->fetchedMessage = $sql_fetchMessage->fetchColumn();

          // Close database connection.
          $conn = null;
?>
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en-US">
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>Edit message</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/styles/edit_message.css">
              <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/edit-message_icon.png">
            </head>
            <body>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div id="messageEdit_wrapper">
                    <div class="messageEdit">
                      <h2><em>Edit Message Form</em></h2>
                      <form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <label for="editedMessage">Edit message<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="editedMessage" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($this->fetchedMessage) ?>" maxlength="191"/>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit_edited-message"><strong>Send</strong></button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </body>
          </html>
<?php
        } else {
          // Close database connection.
          $conn = null;
          // See the function above.
          $this->ErrorMessage_Redirect();
        }
      }
    }

    public function messageUpdate() {
      // Function(s) relating to login.
      require '../login/login-logout-access_functions.php';

      // Check if user is logged in, running one of the login related function(s).
      LoggedInCheck($this->LOGIN_PAGE);
      LastActivityLogOutCheck($this->LOGOUT_FILE);

      // Check if message isn't empty.
      if ('' === trim($this->updatedMessage)) {
        // Redirect to messages page, because the id is somehow empty.
        header('Location: '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE . '?Editempty');
        // Stop the script.
        exit;
      // Check if message doesn't exceed certain length.
      } else if (strlen($this->updatedMessage) > $this->String_MAX_LENGTH) {
        // Redirect to messages page, because the id is somehow empty.
        header('Location: '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE . '?EditStringLengthExceeded');
        // Stop the script.
        exit;
      } else {
        // For connecting to the database.
        require '../../databases/personalWebserver_PDOmysqlconnect.php';

        // Update database table with new message.
        $sql_messageUpdate = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `messageInfo` SET `message` = :updatedMessage WHERE `ID` = :message_id AND `username` = :username");
        $sql_messageUpdate->bindValue(':updatedMessage', $this->updatedMessage, PDO::PARAM:STR);
        $sql_messageUpdate->bindValue(':message_id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM:INT);
        $sql_messageUpdate->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM:STR);

        // Check if message is actually updated.
        if ($sql_messageUpdate->execute()) {
          // Close database connection.
          $conn = null;
          // Redirect to messages page, because the id is somehow empty.
          header('Location: '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE . '?EditSuccess');
          // Stop the script.
          exit;
        } else {
          // Close database connection.
          $conn = null;
          // Redirect to messages page, because the id is somehow empty.
          header('Location: '.$this->MESSAGES_PAGE . '?EditFailure');
          // Stop the script.
          exit;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Check if info was submitted.
  if (isset($_POST['submit_edited-message'])) {
    // Calling above class 'editMessage', and passing along value.
    $editMessage = new editMessage($_GET['id'], $_POST['editedMessage']);
    // Run function inside of class.
    $editMessage->messageUpdate();
  } else {
    // Calling above class 'editMessage', and passing along value.
    $editMessage = new editMessage($_GET['id'], '');

    // Check if id is set.
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
      // Executing function inside of class above.
      $editMessage->formSubmit();
    } else {
      header('Location: '.$editMessage->MESSAGES_PAGE);
      exit;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `PARAM:INT` should be `PARAM_INT`

Comment: It would also have been useful to cut down the code to the relevant section, posting all this code for a problem in one specific function makes it more difficult to help.